# Openvino node output

Tags: openvino

Environment: python=3.8.13, openvino=2022.3.0

Hi,
I intended to get the node output of my model.[Model structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4xWy.png)
The method I tried was: openvino.runtime.Output
[openvino.rutime.Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq9tU.png)

However, i found openvino.runtime was calling _pyopenvino, which was an empty **init** file. Thus the Output class was missing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhXpa.png)

Is it a bug of openvino=2022.3.0?
Or any other method to get the intermediate output of a IR model under openvino?

Appreciate for your help!

Trie: reinstall openvino=2022.2.0, openvino=2022.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the code I tried to call the read_model method.
[image1: screen shot calling the read_model method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O916r.png)

```html
from openvino.runtime import Core

ie = Core()
model_path = 'openvino_folder/testSimplifiedModel_3.simplified.xml'
```

Then I goto the runtime.Core file and found this:
[image2: Core class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucdh3.png)

Maybe I installed the OpenVino in a wrong way? Current openvino version = 2022.3.0.

Comment: Please share the full code snippet that you're trying to execute and the error you get afterwards. The first screenshot is your IDE's feature which might not be working perfectly. Try writing the code according to the developer documentation at http://docs.openvino.ai and then execute it. Additionally the ie_api.py file from your second screenshot contains the Python code to what we now call OV API 1.0. The new API 2.0 is defined elsewhere using pybind11 and that's why you don't see the symbols in Python files. You can also run an interactive session using ipython and test OV there.

Comment: Hi Tomdl and Zul, Thank you for the helping! With jupyter notebook under anaconda, the  _pyopenvino.pyd file successfully loaded.  Thus method like [opvenvino.runtime.Read_model] all became accessible. In a conclusion, the issue was with my IDE which is [pycharm professional 2021.1]. I might use wrong setting in the IDE. I will then search method for intermediate layer output while running a CNN model under jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

```
from openvino.runtime import Core

ie = Core()
classification_model_xml = "model/classification.xml"
model = ie.read_model(model=classification_model_xml)
model.output(0).any_name
```

Refer [here](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.3/notebooks/002-openvino-api-with-output.html) for more info.

Comment: Hello Zul,

It seems the openvino=2022.2.0 removed the Core.read_model() function. Instead they use Core.complied_model() directly.

Refers to the previous question, I found out the issue happened with the __pyopenvino. pyd file. Openvion=2022.2.0 seems to had enclosed some function into the pyd file. While the pyd file failed to be loaded in my windows environment.

Comment: Can you share the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The read_model method is still there https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/api/ie_python_api/_autosummary/openvino.runtime.Core.html#openvino.runtime.Core

You should be able to get the output of the entire model using the suggested `model.output(0)` method call. If you need to access the output of an intermediate operator in the graph you can use something like `model.get_ops()[10].output(0)` where 10 is the index of the operation you're interested in.

Comment: Hi Zul and Tomdol, here is the code I tried to call the read_model method. Since i am new to stackoverflow and don't know how to add image into a comment, I will post the code blow.